# Casting structs to add definition to a shared-memory block in a SIMD application

Tags: c++, casting, shared-memory, simd, avx

I am building an application that requires the use of a large block of shared memory space of type double. This block needs to be byte aligned to ensure proper loading into SIMD registers. For example

```
double *ptr_x = (double *)_mm_malloc(sizeof(double) * 40, 32);
```

Internally, there are several calculations that use the allocated memory (this is where the SIMD processing comes in). It is more convenient to use variable names with appropriate class functions to make the code legible. Rather than performing the calculations and then moving the values to this memory block, I want to use the local variables to make the calculations but have those variables pointing back to the memory.

One way I have tried is to form data structures like:

```
struct Position{
double xCoord;
double yCoord;
double zCoord;
double zeroPad;
};

struct Velocity{
double xCoord;
double yCoord;
double zCoord;
double zeroPad;
};
```

and, define pointers to these structs, and reinterpret_cast pointers from the block of memory as follows:

```
Position *posCar;
Velocity *velCar;

posCar = reinterpret_cast<Position*>(ptr_x + 16);
velCar = reinterpret_cast<Position*>(ptr_x + 20);
```

Is there a preferred way to performing this mapping? Is this compiler safe? For this case, the structs are always of type double and come in groups of 4 to match the __m256d vector definition.

Appreciate any insight into a more preferred approach or the wisdom of experience in an issue that may crop up.

Comment: Typically it's not very efficient to use a SIMD vector to hold a geometry vector or point, despite their names.  You want all 4 (or 8 float) members of a SIMD vector to be the *same kind of element*, so you can do the same operation on 4 or 8 points at once without any shuffling.  Since lane-crossing shuffles (between high and low half) are even worse (especially in AVX1) than within a `__m128` float vector, this is not great.  Use a Struct of Arrays if you can: `struct coords {double *X, *Y, *Z};`.   See https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/

Comment: @Peter- Thanks for the comment. I have been following your posts across SO on SIMD vectorization. If you take it as fact that there is a performance gain, any concern with how I am casting back to the block doubles memory structure?

Comment: That looks reasonable.  One concern is that passing these pointers to something else could lose the fact that they're non-overlapping, possibly hurting auto-vectorization.  The fact that they have different struct tags might be enough for a C++ compiler to assume non-overlapping even without `Position *__restrict function_arg`.  But helping the compiler figure out (lack of) aliasing is always a problem for any pointer thing when you can't just copy the data into a local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a preferred way to performing this mapping?

It’s subjective. C++ books say the preferred one is `reinterpret_cast` like you are doing. Personally, I think C-style casts like `(Position*)( ptr_x + 16 )` is more readable.

Also if you have these things at sequential addresses, consider defining a larger structure with both position and velocity.

> Is this compiler safe?

I think the language standard says “undefined behavior”. In reality on AMD64 processors this works fine in all 4 major compilers.

And one more thing.

> I want to use the local variables to make the calculations but have those variables pointing back to the memory.

You can, but if these calculations are complicated and involve several steps, consider the performance implications. Memory is generally slow, several orders of magnitude slower than registers.

For optimal performance, you should do something like that:

```
__m256d pos = _mm256_loadu_pd( &posCar->x );
__m256d vel = _mm256_loadu_pd( &velCar->x );
// ..update these vectors somehow
_mm256_storeu_pd( &posCar->x, pos );
_mm256_storeu_pd( &velCar->x, vel );
```